# Pagination based on field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a model called fixtures which is accessible through the localhost:3000/fixtures URL only for admin users

This model has a field called gameweekno which I want to use as the pagination field so that fixtures are displayed to the admin relative to their gameweek. Is there any way of creating pagination based on a field such as the gameweekno?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `default_scope` on gameweekno in you fixture model.

`default_scope order("gameweekno [ASC|DESC]")`

Now when you paginate then fixtures will be display as ASC or DESC gameweekno.

If You are using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) gem then you could do as

```
Fixture.order('gameweekno ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: The code seems to be compiling without errors but the fixtures are not yet being paginated

Comment: Are you using will paginate gem. you can find here https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki. Go through it. I think it will solve your problem.